# Influencing how mysql-cli-client displays results from select queries

Tags: mysql

Is it possible to alter the way mysql on CL displays a result from select. This questions is aimed at a link or the propper term for this feature, so I can google it myself.

But specifically - is it possible to have a select result displayed as:

```
A: a
B: b
C: c
```

instead of:

```
A | B | C
----------
a | b | c
```

?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select * from Table\G
```

you end the query with a \G instead of a semicolon.